# Domino Data Services /api/data/collections/unid/XXX returns documents from different view

Tags: ibm-domino

After getting DDS running on our web server, I started testing some REST requests.  The /api/data/collections request does return a list of the views on the DB.

Two views in question are named ClaimedByMe and ClaimedByOthers.  When I look at these in my Notes client, the ClaimedByMe view has 3 documents and the ClaimedByOthers has 0 documents.  If I do a GET against ClaimedByMe it returns an empty list.  If I do a GET against ClaimedByOthers, it returns a list of the 3 documents in the ClaimedByMe view.  I'm not sure why it's getting mixed up like this.  I've verified the UNID of each view being returned by DDS against what I'm seeing in Designer and the UNIDs are correct.  I don't think this is a configuration problem.

Comment: I was suspecting view aliases but if view UnIDs are correct it shouldn't be that. Did you also check the UnIDs of documents returned? Next thing I thought about was Readers-items on documents.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, but I updated my ACL so that Anonymous had no access.  Then from my REST testing client, I did a server authentication POST request.  Now when I GET the views, they return the correct documents.  Not sure why it did that.....

Comment: Strange but seems to be related to access rights somehow. Now that it's solved it would be good to write that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: serverfault won't let me answer my own question until 8 hours after since my serverfault rep is only 6 :-/
will do it in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the ACL of my DB so that Anonymous did not have any access, I was able to do a server auth request through my REST test utility, followed by GET requests to the respective views and the collections of documents returned was now correct.  I don't know why it was related to an ACL change, but seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: This could be related to you having response documents included in the view's selection formula, but having no way of showing the documents because the responses' parent documents are not displayed. For instance because the selection formula is not using @AllDescendants but something less optimal.

Comment: Thanks for the thought.  Unfortunately, there were no response documents.  Being only a test DB, there's only a handful of documents, so I was expecting to see the same collection of documents as in the Notes client.